# How create procedure to retrieve data from three tables with user inserted data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three tables `DEPARTMENTS`, `SEMESTER` and `SUBJECTS`

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENTS
(
    D_ID INT PRIMARY KEY identity(1, 1),
    department_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE SEMESTER
(
    D_ID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES departments(D_ID),
    sem_id INT PRIMARY KEY identity(1, 1),
    semester INT CHECK
        (semester BETWEEN 1 AND 8) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE SUBJECTS
(
    D_ID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES departments(D_ID),
    sem_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES semester(sem_id),
    sub_id INT PRIMARY KEY identity(1, 1),
    sub_name VARCHAR(50),
    syllabus VARBINARY(MAX),
    exam_format VARBINARY(MAX)
);
```

If user insert `department_name` in `DEPARTMENTS`  table and `semester` from `semester` table then how to get `sub_name` from `subject`

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Could you show us some sample data? What is the relationship between these tables? 

SELECT sub_name
FROM [SUBJECTS] 
Inner join SEMESTER ON semester.sem_id = SUBJECTS.sem_id
inner join  DEPARTMENTS ON DEPARTMENTS.D_ID = SEMESTER.D_ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your design is wrong. you don't need to have a reference from Subject to Departments because Department is accessible through Semester and the D_Id in Subject is redundant, IMHO.

Second, what is your criteria for retrieving subject?

```
Select Sub_Name
from Subjects as sbj
inner join Departments as dpt on sbj.D_Id = dpt.D_Id
inner join Semester as smt on sbj.sem_id = smt.sem_id
where (YOUR CRITERIA)
```

This is basically the general correlation among your tables,
so you could specify the conditions and list of fields to be retrieved.

However it's best to rectify your design first and then access department
through Semester :

```
inner join Departments as dpt on smt.D_Id = dpt.D_Id
```

thereby you're gonna use the dependency in semester rather than subjects!

p.s.

if the department in subject is different from the on in semester
then your layout is good as it is, but if they're same thing then 
you can get rid of the latter

Comment: Typing mistake: smt.sem_id

Comment: sir can you please explain me how to use  "inner join Departments as dpt on smt.D_Id = dpt.D_Id" along with Select Sub_Name
from Subjects as sbj
inner join Departments as dpt on sbj.D_Id = dpt.D_Id
inner join Semester as smt on sbj.sem_id = smt.sem_id
where (YOUR CRITERIA) in store procedure

Comment: well, the "as dpt" will create an alias for Departments table name, this is just for the sake of brevity so your query would be less wordy, you can use Departments as well invariably. same goes for sbj in the case of Subjects. the Criteria is your Where clause. you can put in any condition that you may have or omit the whole where clause altogether if you don't have any conditions. the subject_name in the select list is there for demonstration. you can replace it with a comma separated list of any number of fields which are reachable through your joins.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `join` here

```
select sub.sub_name,dep.department_name,sem.semester
from subjects sub
    join departments dep on dep.d_id = sub.d_id
    join semester sem on sem.sem_id = sub.sem_id;
```